# Nested Scrollview not perfectly working

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is when I scroll after toolbar collapses and the imagevie is hidden the contents inside the cardview are getting scrolled but not completely getting scrolled until the last.
Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/internationalcover"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="78dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/flexible.example.cardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:contentPaddingLeft="16dp"
            app:contentPaddingRight="16dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            android:text="International Admissions"
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#1a237e"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/para1"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutusp1"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/para2"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutusp2"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/para3"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
            android:text="@string/aboutusp3"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```